# jquery extend method (extend order)

Tags: jquery

I use the extend method to add a button to my datatables:

```
var buttons = commissionDialog.dialog("option", "buttons");
$.extend(buttons, { 'Create Commission': function () { InsertOrUpdateCommission(); } });
commissionDialog.dialog("option", "buttons", buttons);
```

it works but the button order is:
old1, old2, new1 (here: Create commission).

I want to have:
new1, old1, old2.

How to do this?

Create of the Dialog:

```
function CreateViewCommissionDialog() {
    //Dialog View Commission
    commissionDialog = $("#viewCommissionDialogForm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 550,
        width: 700,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function () {
                commissionDialog.dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function () {
        },
        open: function (event, ui) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the initial [buttons](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons) as an array, then you can use [.unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to insert the new button at the beginning of the array like

```
var btns = dialog.dialog('option', 'buttons');
btns.unshift({
    text: "New Button",
    click: function () {
    }
});
dialog.dialog('option', 'buttons', btns);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/78kGq/)

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt work for me... says "method unshift are not available here"

Comment: @ReneK because your buttons object is not an array... can you share how the dialog is created

Comment: @ReneK define it as an array `buttons: [{
        text: "Cancel",
        click: function () {
            commissionDialog.dialog("close");
        }
    }]`

Comment: Doesn't work. As soon as I do this as an array, the commissionDialog.dialog('close') throws an error because he didnt know the commissonDialog object any more